# What is the keyboard shortcut for adding a new file to a project in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I used to be able to press **shift+alt+c** to add a new file to a project, but my Visual Studio updated and I seem to have lost this keyboard shortcut.

If i go to *Tools -> options... -> Environment -> Keybord*, I can see a huge list of commands that can have keybord shortcuts assigned to them. What is the command for adding a new item to a project?

I know there is a new *shift+F2* [shortcut that lets you quick add a new class.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022), but I'm interested in the full *Add New Item* menu.

Comment: Shortcut keys are displayed on the menu to the right of the menu text.  So Ctrl+N for a new file, Shift+Alt+A for an existing file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the **shift+alt+c** shortcut for adding new items to projects is apparently gone in new versions of Visual Studio. I found a [mapping of commands and keyboard shortcuts from before the update here.](https://jbwyatt.com/VSShortcuts.pdf)

The **shift+alt+c** shortcut used to be linked to the command *Project.AddClass*.

So If you navigate to *Tools -> options... -> Environment -> Keybord*, and then search for *Project.AddClass*, you can re-add the **shift+alt+c** keyboard shortcut and use the shortcut as befor.